# Doctor Who: How do you fight a time war and its consequences?

Tags: doctor-who, time-war

When *Doctor Who* was rebooted in 2005, one of the main themes since then was the "Last Great Time War" that pitted the Daleks against the Time Lords.

But how did the Daleks and the Timelords actually fight a time war? Did they send their forces deep into the past of your enemy? Change history so that your enemy is weaker or perhaps doesn't exits?

Certainly, the TV story "Genesis of the Daleks" is taken to be the first step in the time war by the Time Lords. But what about the Daleks?

Certainly, according to this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_War_(Doctor_Who)#Doctor_Who_comic_strip), the "Order of the Black Sun", sent an agent back in time to just around the time the Time Lords were starting their time travel experiments, only for the event to help them establish time travel.

Comment: Related (answer includes some details to answer your question): [What were the effects of the Great Time War on the universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/80306/31394)

Comment: How do you fight a time war? _Very carefully._

Comment: In a wibbly-wobbly way?

Comment: In a timely fashion?

Comment: My understanding is every attempt to delete the Daleks from history spawned something worse.  It's probably also worth noting that the Davies era notion of war was vastly more surreal than Moffat's.  For example Davies had the entire war and the Fall of Gallifrey still burning but locked behind a time lock wall wiping out all traces of Daleks and Timelords from the universe.  Moffat had the Daleks shoot themselves in a circle.  The War Doctor has had a novel and audio stories so that would be the most canon answer. More canon than a trek novel but less controlled than a star wars EU.

Comment: If you want semi-canonical in-universe answers, you can have a look at the Time War ranges (_e.g._ _Gallifrey_, _The War Doctor_ and _The War Master_) from Big Finish. Not sure you will be much wiser, but maybe you'll be entertained.

Comment: Possibly also relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Is_How_You_Lose_the_Time_War